# cordova media plugin isnt working on android 4.4 and 5.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

i have tried running cordova media plugin in both kitkat and lollipop but it shows no response. 
Not even the 3rd parameter for error's function is running.
I have also read almost every article or question about this problem and tried every way i could but nothing worked.
All i finally concluded was that this plugin is not fully supported in android versions above 4.1

I have tried:

```
<script>
    document.body.onload="ready()";
  function ready()
  {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",function() {
    var src;
    // src's value
  var med=new Media(src,
  function() {
  alert("success");
  },
  function(e)
  {
  alert("failed code: "+e);
  });
  med.play();
  med.release();},false);
  }
  </script>
```

here is what i have tried replacing with *//src's value*

`src = 'cdvfile://audio.mp3';`

`src = 'file:///android_asset/www/audio.mp3';`

`src = "cdvfile:///android_asset/www/audio.mp3";`

`src = "audio.mp3";`

even after that stupid conclusion i wrote about up there, i still am doubtful that how it still runs on some devices with same os. So, any ideas of making audio files play in cordova app?

**MORE INFO:**
1>My project structure

```
appName
     |___www
           |___[+]css
           |___[+]js
           |___index.html
           |___[+]img
           |___audio.mp3
```

2>I am targeting 6.3.0 marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

Media definitely works for me on marshmallow - albeit I use wav files rather than mp3. I use

```
audioFail = loadAudio('sounds/no.wav'); where the file is stored in www/sounds
```

The media constructor is asynchronous but your code uses med immediately after issuing the call to the constructor - have you confirmed that med exists and is defined before you try to call `med.play()`?